# limit with two variable

Tags: limits

How to calculate:

$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}        \frac{5x^6 + y^2}{x^3 + 2y}
$$

I think the result should be $0$, but how do I prove it? I tried by the definition, but I could not resolve that.

I cannot use the different paths to prove that, because there are an infinity of paths and I would have to calculate them all, and that's impossible. 
I believe the only way is by definition.

Comment: Use the path $x=kt$ and $y=kt^3$

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Well, it's so trivial :P

Comment: @Mann, I get $\left({5k^5+k\over k^2+2}\right)t^3\to0$ as $t\to0$ from the path you suggest.

Comment: Then its simply zero. ^^

Comment: But there are an infinity of paths,,, So only that path would not prove that limit is 0. I think the only way is using the definition of limit, but, like I said, I'm having problems there.

Comment: @Mann, I don't think so.

Comment: Check the path $y=-x^3/2$.  The quotient is not  even defined along this path for any $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.

Comment: @Dr.MV, it's standard (in some books, at least) to approach limits only along paths that stay in the domain of the function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:  Let $y=-{1\over2}x^3+kx^p$, so that the denominator simplifies to $2kx^p$.  Look for a $p$ that will cancel with what you get in the numerator.

**Added later**:  If we approach $(0,0)$ along a path of the form $y=-{1\over2}x^3+kx^p$, we find that

$${5x^6+y^2\over x^3+2y}={5x^6+{1\over4}x^6-kx^{3+p}+k^2x^{2p}\over 2kx^p}={21\over8k}x^{6-p}-{1\over2}x^3+{k\over2}x^p$$

If we now let $p=6$, we get

$${5x^6+y^2\over x^3+2y}={21\over8k}-x^3+{k\over2}x^6\to{21\over8k}\quad\text{as }x\to0$$

Since different values of $k$ give different results, we conclude there is no limit.

(Remark:  The proof that there is no limit could be written more tersely by setting $p=6$ from the get go.  I presented things the way I did in part to show that the choice of $p$ is more or less forced.)

Comment: To the OP:  your edit to your question indicates my hint didn't help.  If so, please say so, and I'll give a more complete answer.

Comment: When you say cancel, you mean the numerator is now $0$, right? Well this, will give me $0$ for the value of the limit. And I cannot conclude anything from there, since the values I obtained using other paths are also $0$. I think the only way to solve this is using the definition of limit.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user239754, excellent.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume that the limit is defined. See if you can find two paths y = y(x) such that the limits would not be equal.

Comment: I know that and I've tried many of them, they all give me 0. But there are an infinity of ways, so I want to prove it.